# Get content of controller variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with Ionic and I have a problem with my variables of my controller.

This is a part of my index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="ListController" ng-init="showSearch = false; showNavigationBar = false;">

  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive actionbar">
    <div class="item" ng-click="back()" style="background-color: #0022ff; border: none; color: white" ng-hide="previousLevelName == null">
      <i class="ion-chevron-left" style="margin-left: 10px"> {{previousLevelName}}</i>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">FactBook</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-mic-outline" ng-click="showNavigationBar = true"></button>
        <a href="templates/navigation.html">
          <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-browsers-outline"></button>
        </a>
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search" ng-click="showSearchBar = true"></button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
[...]
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

And that's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('starter');
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.content = ["Test1", "Test2"];
    $scope.previousLevelName = null;

    $scope.nextLevel = function(index){
        $scope.previousLevelName = "Level 1";
    }

    $scope.back= function(index){
      //Not implemented yet
    }

}]);
```

I want to see "Level 1" in my header bar when the content of `previousLevelName` is changed (Changed by another page). But nothing happens. What could be the mistake?

**UPDATE:**

html in view:

```
<ion-view view-title="factBook" ng-app="starter">
  <ion-content class="has-header list" ng-controller="ListController">
      <div class="item" ng-repeat="con in content | filter:searchText track by $index">
        <div class="item" ng-click="nextLevel($index)">
          <h2>
            {{con}}
         </h2>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I think it is because a new controller is created when I write `ng-controller="ListController"`. Can I make them singleton?

Comment: Sorry but I can't see you calling nextLevel () in your view !!

Comment: Yes, because it happens in another page. I will update my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your options here are to:

1) Make an Angular service and transfer that variable `previousLevelName` to it. All services in Angular are singletons so you can inject that into your controller and use that instead.

2) Transfer `previousLevelName` onto the `$rootScope`. This will essentially make it a global variable, which is a code smell, but will make your app work.

Let me know if that's clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, arjabbar! I tried to add this:

`app.factory('HeaderContentService', function() {
      var previousLevelName = null;
      return {
          getPreviousLevelName: function(){
            return previousLevelName;
          },
          setPreviousLevelName: function (pln){
            previousLevelName = pln;
     }
  }
})`

But when I want to use it with `$scope.previousLevelName = HeaderContentService.getPreviousLevelName();` I get the error "Can't find variable: HeaderContentService". Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Did you inject it into your controller? Add this to the parameter list like so `app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', '$http', 'HeaderContentService', function($scope, $http, HeaderContentService)`